# Harmonic Dirichlet series

Tags: special-functions, dirichlet-series

The harmonic numbers are defined by
$$ H_n=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j} $$
I have come across the following sum:
$$ g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{H_n} $$
Clearly it converges only for $z<1/e$.  Is it a known function?

Comment: Here's a neat thing: $z^{H_n} = z^{1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n} = z\cdot z^{1/2}\cdot z^{1/3}\cdot\cdots z^{1/n}$ so, when it converges, the sum can be written as $g(z) = z(1+z^{1/2}(1+z^{1/3}(1+z^{1/4}(\cdots))))$.